# Best practices to do frequent disk log writes

Tags: c#, logging, service, disk

I am developing a windows service in C# which will likely write several times per second to a log. I am currently using `System.IO.File.AppendAllText(time + message)` for each operation and I am concerned so many writes may wear out the disk quickly.

Could this be a problem? Should I use a stream and flush every few seconds? Does the windows disk buffer protect against this?

Comment: More things to think about: concurrency? Abnormal termination? Delay for caller? Maximum log size?  Honestly...if it's not a mere exercise you'd better pick a logging framework like NLog

Comment: There's a _lot_ of information about this on the web in general, and this site in specific. Before people will go and repeat what's already on there, please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, I had addressed some of these issues manually and hadn't even considered others. I had superficially looked at log4net and discarded the idea of using it as overkill, but it seems I am going to need it.

Code caster, I focused my search on disk damage because it was my concern, found a question discarded as non-related to programming and little else. Thanks for bringing up the "How to ensure all data..." question.

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to reinvent the wheel? 
Better use some ready [framework](https://www.google.pl/?ion=1&espv=2#q=c%23%20logging%20framework) eg. [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), [SeriLog](https://serilog.net/).

> "Should I use a stream and flush every few seconds?"

What if your app crash with no flush stream? Log go away and you don't know what happens.